# What is $bfr$ in this expression?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, terminology, notation, textbook-erratum

I am reading 'Fundamentals of Quantum Mechanics' by Sakir Erokoc and came across this expression in relation to transition probabilities:
$$\vec p=e \langle \psi_b |bfr|\psi_a \rangle$$
Which can be found [here](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=wrLNBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA333&dq=average+polarization+spontaneous+emission&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiR_p6lxpfMAhWCXBoKHezWA0I4ChDoAQghMAE#v=onepage&q=average%20polarization%20spontaneous%20emission&f=false) (p332). I have tried looking in this book and in other places but I can't deduce what $bfr$ represents here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a LaTeX typo. The author meant to write $\mathbf{r}$, i.e. '\bf{r}' where they've defined \bf as a macro for \mathbf. They forgot the slash.

This indicates you should throw the book in the trash, as it was never properly edited.